# Start TimerService with application on WebLogic

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to start an EJB TimerService timer when my application starts on WebLogic 10.3.5

The Timer is an EJB.  I tried using both ServletContextListener and ApplicationLifecycleListener.

Using ServletContextListener results in:

```
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.ejb.container.timer.ClusteredEJBTimerManager.createTimer(ClusteredEJBTimerManager.java:76)
at weblogic.ejb.container.timer.ClusteredEJBTimerManager.createTimer(ClusteredEJBTimerManager.java:95)
```

When using ApplicationLifecycleListener, I cannot even lookup the EJB.  However, if I just instantiate it as a POJO, I get an NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.oracle.eas.announcements.deliveryengine.ejb.RecipientsPopulationTimerBean.createTimer(RecipientsPopulationTimerBean.java:77)
at com.oracle.eas.announcements.deliveryengine.listeners.AppStartStopListener.postStart(AppStartStopListener.java:48)
```

Any advice on how to create a Timer that is created/removed with an Application on WebLogic 10.3.5 would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you performing JNDI lookup, can you update post with relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Oracle support have confirmed that this is not possible due to the server state.

It turns out that my methodology was wrong, I shouldn't need to create a TimerService at each boot, just once and then use it to control Timers subsequently.